# tabs[0].title returning URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

In my Chrome Extension Javascript code I read the URL and Title of the current tab and then later print them to a table.  However, frequently what is stored for the Title is a repeat of the URL. So when the user opens the Extension and clicks to display the table, the URL is sometimes listed again in the Title column. This happens occasionally, but not all of the time.  If I change 'loading' to 'complete' in the code below, then it happens more often. When it happens I Inspect the web page and check that it does in fact have a proper title tag. 
Here is my code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'loading' && tab.active) {
        chrome.tabs.query(QUERY_INFO, function (tabs) {
            // Get active URL info
            var ACTIVE_URL = tabs[0].url;
            var ACTIVE_URL_TITLE = tabs[0].title;
        });
    }
});
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks!
Jon

Comment: Looks like a bug in Chrome.